# links in split listview not clickable

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a split listview like the one below (from JQM example):

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d">
        <li><a href="index.html">
                <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" />
                <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
                <p>Broken Bells</p>
            </a>
            <a href="lists-split-purchase.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup">Purchase album
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="secondListItem">
                <img src="images/album-hc.jpg" />
                <h3>Warning</h3>
                <p>Hot Chip</p>     
            </a>
            <a href="lists-split-purchase.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup">Purchase album
            </a>
        </li>           
    </ul>
```

This results in een listview with gear buttons to the right of all items.
The example (see first listitem) uses the href to link to another page. this works as expected. The whole button is clickable.

But what I want is to run a javascript function upon clicking the right-side button.
I've attach a clickhandler as follows (see second list item):

```
$('#secondListItem').click(function(){
    console.log('clicked!!');
});
```

Now when I click on the icon of the button nothing happens, clicking the rest of the button works fine.
The problem lies in the additions JQM makes, to make it pretty. I've tried to put clickhandlers on the spans inside the a tag but nothing seems to work.

So, how can I add a clickhandler to the right button? (the second a in the li)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('#secondListItem').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();      // to prevent default browser load activity
    console.log('clicked!!');
});
```

OR

```
$('ul').on('click', '#secondListItem', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked!!');
});
```